# Magento 2: Error in header at checkout due to module installation

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, design

Whenever I enable a custom module (payment) the header display with design errors:

- Logo is removed
- Search bar, header links and minicart don't disappear

I've tested 2 different modules (from different providers) and the result is the same, so I guess it's not a problem with those modules but something in my installation/theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to create from here http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module & check. Still design issue?

Comment: please check your payment module checkout_index_index.xml file, in this file header and footer are removed by extension so please remove those line from xml file.

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks, I had to make some changes to the xml file from the provider's module and now the issue is solved.